# Rendering Error on UITabBar Icon

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, xcode5, uitabbar

I've designed an `UITabBar` icon for my Application.
The HIG for `iOS 7` states that `UITabBar` icons should be about 55x55 pixel (for a retina device).

Unfortunatly my Icon does not seem to render correctly:

Original Icon:

[image: Original Icon]

How it is Rendered in Xcode and the iOS Simulator:

[image: Rendered Icon]

Has Anyone Experienced something similar, or has any Ideas how to fix this?

**EDIT://**

Nevermind, I already solved it.

Illustrator just filled the rectangles with white instead of making them transparent which resulted in a fine looking icon on white but a odd looking icon when used in an `UITabBar`.

Comment: Are you using the same icon for the `image`and `selectedImage` properties of the tab bar item?

Comment: i've been setting the image via the Storyboard where you can't set a separate selected and unselected image. Setting it by Code renders no Image at All.

Comment: Check in your code if you have set tint color of your UITabBar to this color.